# Why is the word "hat" at the end of the sentence?

Tags: word-order

Can you please tell me why the word **"hat"** goes at end of the sentence and not before **"gesagt"** in the following sentence:

> "Das ist was der Doktor mir gesagt hat."

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. What makes you assume the "other" word order and how does "the other" look in your example?

Answer (score 3):

"hat" here is at the end of a subordinate clause, which starts with "was". So it follows the word order for subordinate clauses, where the verb is at the end and in a compound tense, the auxiliary follows the past participle. However, if the conjunction had been one of "und, oder, aber, denn, sondern", it would have been main clause type word order, ie auxiliary verb (hat) before past participle (gesagt).

Comment: And exactly because "was der Doktor mir gesagt hat" is a subordinate clause, it must be separated from the main clause ("das ist") with a comma.